# Brother MFC665CW on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: printing

I've been trying to install Brother MFC665CW on Ubuntu for months now. About five minutes ago, it finally said "New Printer Detected" and shows it in the list of my printers, but from the scanner/printer, when I send a file over it said "Connecting to PC..." but it obviosuly isn't doing anything. Any ideas on this? It looks like they aren't connecting to one another, just detecting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the installation instructions for the [lpr driver](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html) and the [cups wrapper](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html)?

Don't forget to have a look at **Step 2** (pre-required procedures) for your Ubuntu version.

Check the **CUPS interface**

```
http://localhost:631/printers/
```

for the correct settings of your printer.

Comment: What would this do, though? What do I do after this?

Comment: All of them say "Idle."

Comment: Is there any printer? Is it connected and idle? If so, check the connection, print a test page...

Comment: Are you using 12.04 in 64Bit?

Comment: 32bit. They are all connected and idle.